# werkzeug module not matching hashed password

Tags: python, hash, passwords

Im currently following along w a video trying to build this login system for a site, but each time I call the werkzeug function to check the hash of the password against the one used to sign up, it returns invalid password. What am I doing wrong to make the hashes end up different even though I'm entering the same password as I did to sign up?

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for
from .models import User
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from . import db
from flask_login import login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user


auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)

@auth.route('/sign-up', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sign_up():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('email')
        first_name = request.form.get('firstName')
        password1 = request.form.get('password1')
        password2 = request.form.get('password2')

        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if user:
            flash('Email already exists.', category='error')
        elif len(email) < 4:
            flash('Email must be greater than 3 characters.', category='error')
        elif len(first_name) < 2:
            flash('First name must be greater than 1 character.', category='error')
        elif password1 != password2:
            flash('Passwords don\'t match.', category='error')
        elif len(password1) < 7:
            flash('Password must be at least 7 characters.', category='error')
        else:
            new_user = User(email=email, first_name=first_name, password=generate_password_hash(password1, method='sha256',))
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Account created!', category='success')
            return redirect(url_for('views.home'))
    return render_template("sign_up.html")

@auth.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('email')
        password = request.form.get('password')
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if user:
            if check_password_hash(user.password, password):
                flash('Logged in successfully!', category='success')
                login_user(user, remember=True)
                return redirect(url_for('views.home'))
            else:
                flash('Incorrect password, try again.', category='error')
        else:
            flash('Email does not exist.', category='error')

    return render_template("login.html", user=current_user)


@auth.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
```

Comment: Have you tried speciying the hashing method in `check_password_hash`?

Comment: I tried  if check_password_hash(user.password, password, method='sha256'):, but it just gives TypeError: check_password_hash() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method', so I think you can only use 2 args for the function

Comment: what about hashing without specifiying the method?

Comment: I guess no password hash was stored in the first place, because the [documentation](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/werkzeug.generate_password_hash.html#werkzeug.generate_password_hash) doesn't mention sha256. It only mentions "sha1" and "pbkdf2". You should try them first.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Finally figured out what was wrong

the password = request.form.get('password') i was declaring for the login function, was actually supposed to be the same as the one on sign_up(password1), so I just changed it to

password1 = request.form.get('password1')

and now it can check and log in successfully.

Thanks for your help guys, definitely gave me some good advice to go off.